# why are browsers mis-rendering <span>, <a>, <em>, &c?

Tags: browser, tags, rendering

go to this [example page](http://www.sixintheclip.com/problem.php).  as you can see, the link, the words 'Call' and 'Email' are all aligned lower than the rest of the text.  this is also happening when i wrap markup in ,  or suchlike tags.

i've got a reset going on, so... what the hell is causing this?  this shows up in ALL browsers, so it's not a Chrome issue or Safari issue, or whatever-browser issue.

WR!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because theres a padding of 4px on those elements, check your rules

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-image: initial;
}
```

that includes span which you are using on the words Call and Email

Comment: schiesse.  totally missed that; thought i'd taken them all out.  noob oversight... thx.  :'(

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the "reset default browser CSS". I wouldn't recommend such things anyway. Particularly, the `padding` of 4px on `a` elements together with `vertical-align: middle` causes them to be rendered lower than normal text which is not inside any of the specified tags. See http://jsfiddle.net/nxzEA/ for a minimal example.